# Ejecutar primera acción de Click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Necesito de su ayuda para que se ejecute el primer click a un botón y no los siguientes si se realizan muchos clicks. Usé la función de `jquery`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").dblclick(function(){

    });
});
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){

    });
});
```

pero no tuve éxito.

Existe forma de tomar la acción del primer click?

Answer (score 1):

*JQuery* dispone de un método llamado [one](https://api.jquery.com/one/) el cual, se ejecutará solo una vez por el tipo de elemento del DOM al cual es asociado; por ejemplo:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="btn">Dame click</button>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    <script>
        let btn = $("#btn")
        
        btn.one("click", function(event){
          console.log("solo el primer click")
        })
    </script>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: que pasaria si se refresca la pagina?

Comment: aparte de one creo que deberia involucar a backend o en su defecto usar localstorage

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas obvio que se me ocurre es bloquear el botón al ser presionado:

```
$('#btn').attr("disabled", true);
```

Con eso haces que con el primer click se el único al que se reacciones, pero el botón tendrá apariencia de deshabilitado.

Otra forma es poniendo la acción del primer click en una funcion fuera de jQuery que defina una variable interna como bandera de que ya ha sido usada, algo como esto:

```
function first()
{
    if ( typeof first.clicked !== 'undefined' ) {               
           //La accion que realices con el primer click;
           first.clicked = true;
    }
}
```

Y en tu código jQuery puedes llamar esta función o, directamente desde el boton.

Saludos.♣

Comment: De este modo lo definiría? $(document).ready(first(){
    $("#btn").click(first(){

    });
}); gracias por las respuestas

Comment: No somplemente asi, $(document).ready($("#btn").click(first(){ }));
De cualquie manera la funcion **first()** debe ser declarada fuera de lo de jQuery. Espero te ayude ♣

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la mejor opción sería deshabilitarlo hasta que cierres el nuevo popup de detalle.

Deshabilitar:

```
$('#btn').attr("disabled", true);
```

Habilitar:

```
$('#btn').attr("disabled", false);
```